# How can I force PHP not to show errors?

Tags: php, security, error-handling

I had scan my site and got Security Warning:

```
Plugin: "Web Application Information Disclosure"
Category: "CGI abuses"
Synopsis: The remote web application discloses path information.
Description: At least one web application hosted on the remote web server
discloses the physical path to its directories when a malformed
request is sent to it.
```

My site is in Wordpress, how can I force it not to show PHP errors?

This is what it shows sometimes:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): User ubinaryc_host already has more than 'max_
user_connections' active connections in /home/ubinaryc/public_html/wp-in
cludes/wp-db.php on line 1143
```

Comment: Change display_errors in your php.ini to 0.

Comment: where can I find this file ? I don't have it in the ftp I searched in the cPanel & the machine without success, can I add it to the config file or the setting file ?

Comment: Check your host's documentation, or contact their support channel. You may also be able to use `set_ini('display_errors', 0);` in your WP config file.

Comment: That's `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` rather than `set_ini()` as suggested...